# how to set max height for CJuiAutoComplete drop downlist in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui, yii

I want to set max-height for CJuiAutoComplete drop downlist in Yii

Here is my code:

```
echo $form->label($model, 'name');
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'name',
    'attribute'=>'name',
    'model'=>$model,
    'sourceUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('mytask'),
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options'=>array(
            'minLength'=>'2',
            'showAnim'=>'fold',
            'max-height'=>'100px',
            ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'style'=>'height:18px;width:400px;',
    ),
));
```

'max-height'=>'100px' is not working, anyone knows how to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try adding 
`'max-height'=>'100px'`, inside htmlOptions ,

```
'style'=>'height:18px;width:400px;max-height:100px;',
```

Comment: add max-height:100px !important;